# downloaded image from url is not showing in view

Tags: android

i want to ask that i am downloading images from url means i had url in string array and on button click i move to next url and downloaded image from server.
it runs perfectly on samsung galaxy s2 mobile and image downloading and displaying in view but in some other mobile of small size screen it is not displaying in view but in some it displaying ...what is the reason behind this what is happening ..i use setimageBitmap() in onpostExecute() and it work well for samsung galaxys2 what about for lower range mobile why it is not displaying ..i also change the image view height and width but not solve..but some time it is displaying..

my code is below..

log cat:

```
  logcat out  put :



   DEBUG/skia(231): --- decoder->decode returned false
  INFO/System.out(231): Bitmap :: null
  INFO/System.out(231): Bitmap on post :: null
 WARN/InputManagerService(63): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of:   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c17828
INFO/System.out(231): Message sent
 INFO/image url/////(231):   http://www.artealdiaonline.com/var/artealdia_com/storage/images/argentina/agenda/exposiciones_muestras/carlos_cruz-diez/carlos_cruz-diez2/507989-1-esl-AR/Carlos_Cruz-Diez.jpg
   INFO/System.out(231): Bitmap :: android.graphics.Bitmap@44d64750
     INFO/System.out(231): Bitmap on post :: android.graphics.Bitmap@44d64750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for fetching Image ::

```
 ImageButton   tran_btn_skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tran_btn_skip);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    "http://www.hermann-uwe.de/files/images/blue_flower.preview_0.jpg")
                    .getContent());
            tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

and try this in mobile device (`not in emulator`)if you load from your server but, if you load from any another server ten you can show in emulator.

**Update::**

[image: see]

```
package com.progressbar;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class progressbar extends Activity  {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton   tran_btn_skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.login);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                    "http://www.artealdiaonline.com/var/artealdia_com/storage/images/argentina/agenda/exposiciones_muestras/leila_tschopp3/baja-leila_tschopp_-_river_-acrilico_sobre_tela-130x150_cm_-_2011/498599-1-esl-AR/BAJA-Leila_Tschopp_-_River_-acrilico_sobre_tela-130x150_cm_-_2011.jpg")
                    .getContent());
            tran_btn_skip.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: HEY ON PRINTING System.out.println("Bitmap :: " + bitmap);,bitmap value is null

Comment: first tell me are you getting from particular url or own n/w server

Comment: please try my code i have update with temporary URL it is flower image just  try in emulator

Comment: but make sure you connection cant loose

Comment: hi nick ur url is working and my  url is http://www.artealdiaonline.com/var/artealdia_com/storage/images/argentina/agenda/exposiciones_muestras/carlos_cruz-diez/carlos_cruz-diez/507986-1-esl-AR/Carlos_Cruz-Diez.jpg    is not working why?

Comment: iamge is showing from ur url but if i replace it with my then not...why?

Comment: http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?galleryID=4 in this url the tag for image url is "ImageExposiciones" i parse  it collect url in array and use for downloading...u can also see it

Comment: just tell me in your android device, internet connectivity are come from USB?

Comment: as i said it working on some emulator and problem in wqvga of 5554 emulator

Comment: means for small screen it is not working but ur image url is working fine

Comment: first tell me you have device or not?(i am angrily with your attitude)

Comment: i have device LG Optimus One v 2.2

Comment: are you get internet from Your pc or Wifi or 3g?

Comment: internet from 3G in my mobile

Comment: i just help you because i have also face problem with emulator which i have load my own server file but when i have insert it in device it working fine main reason is network. you cant load image if you use network connection in device or pc

Comment: as you show in screen short i have successfully load your image.so again check in manifest file that all permission are give and check correctly

Comment: in my pc i am using network connection then also it is not working i am also wondering why image is  display in one emulator and in other its not

Comment: nikunj wait i am sending u video url of my problem,so that u can see my problem in emulator

Comment: goto your project property >> click android >> and give me screen short of `Project Build Target`

Comment: pls see my log cat output also in my qus. part above...thanks

Comment: choose android 2.2 target instead of google api if you are not use map

Comment: nikunj actually i am using google map in my application so if i set target 2.2 then it will show error

Comment: means target target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:10 ?i have try it and its working well on it.so is there any problem for using google apis:7 .then if i will use apis level:10 then what should be the version of my mobile to run it and display downloaded image sucessfull?actully when i set target api:10 then also in my mobile  image is not downloadin...but in my other mobile samsung galaxy s2 it works well...

Comment: hey nikunj pls see my new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452754/display-the-back-and-next-button-between-half-the-height-of-image-android can u also upvote my qus

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
   conn.connect();
   BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
   Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, imageUrl);
   view.setImageBitmap(drawable)
```

Comment: hi  what is "imageUrl" and "url" in ur code pls see on ur code ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code:

```
String imageUrl = "http://someurl.com/example.png";
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
conn.connect();
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
Drawable imageDrawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, imageUrl);
view.setImageBitmap(imageDrawable);
```