# display the back and next button between half the height of image android

Tags: android

i have a problem in xml layout for displaying next and back button besides the image and should be in middle of height of image.

pls see this url

http://screencast.com/t/zE47nb0rkFE

two buttons are above the image,it is left and right but not the middle height of image.
and it should be for every resolution size of screen.

my xml is

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can use scrollview in code like this ::**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView
android:id="@+id/imv"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="55dip"
 />

 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imagegallery"
 android:layout_width="70sp"
  android:layout_height="70sp"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_below="@id/imv"/>
 <ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/Bar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@id/imagegallery"
  android:layout_below="@id/imv"
 />

 <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/textView1" 
  android:text="Art Gallery" 
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

  android:layout_below="@id/imv"
  />
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/textView2" 
  android:textColor="#00C000"
  android:textSize="20dip"
  android:text=" " 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imagegallery"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
  />
  <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/textopeningnow" 
android:text="Opening Now" 
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
/>
 <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/diosas" 
 android:textSize="20dip"
android:text="Diosas/Godesses" 
android:textColor="#00C000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textopeningnow"
/>

    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/back" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="25dip"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"/>
     <Button 
     android:id="@+id/next" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="25dip"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:background="@drawable/rightarrow"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back"
    android:layout_below="@id/diosas" 
  />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/artistname" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text=" " 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageLoader" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd enclose your image in a separate RelativeLayout, and add the buttons to it. It's way too hard to try to achieve what you want with just a global relative layout.

Comment: hey i not understood ..pls can u share ur xml for the same..how u enclose  image in a separate RelativeLayout...thanks

Comment: Go to the UI editor in Eclipse, right-click on the widget you want to enclose in its own layout (in your case it's the picture), and choose "Wrap in Container".